# What Champions are freely available, and how can I get them?

Tags: league-of-legends

My friends and I are started getting into League of Legends. I am enjoying myself enough that I'm considering unlocking a Champion or two.

However, I noticed that some Champions are available online for dirt cheap, with prices such as Liking a Facebook page or Subscribing to a YouTube channel.  I would feel like a complete idiot if I purchased one of the Champions that is available for so little expense.

What Champions can I get for cheap, and how?

Comment: Technically, this questions is kind of localized as they're likely to modify the list of freely-available champions at some point. I'm not sure if it changes often enough to warrant closing this question, but I do consider the correct answer to this question to be one that will not remain static.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Riot technically doesn't offer any champion for free.

What they *do* offer is skins for certain champions -- and if you don't have the champion when you get a skin for it, you get the champion for free.

That said, there are only three:

- Riot Girl Tristana ([for liking LoL on facebook](http://leagueoflegends.com/facebook))
- Unchained Alistar ([for subscribing to Riot youtube](http://leagueoflegends.com/youtube))
- Dreadknight Garen ([following @LoLEU on Twitter *EUW/EUNE only*](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=15167835))

Previous giveaways (No longer available):

- Nightmare cho'gat given by alienware on season 1
- King Rammus for participating in the beta.
- Nightmare Cho'gath champion and skin free giveaway from Alienware (Now ended)
- Caitlyn and Arctic skin in Septembers issue of PC Gamer (US only)
- Kayle and skin for playing 10+ games in season one
- Corki and ufo skin when Riot won Gamer's Choice awards for Multiplayer, Strategy, and PC Game of the Year
- Victorious Jarvan Skin for acchieving Gold / Platinum rank in season 1.
- Dragonflame Shyvana with a gaming mouse (promo on NewEgg)
- Riot Nasus Twitter giveaway in celebration of PAX from MachinimaRealm
- Victorious Janna for Gold/Diamond ranking in Season 2
- Victorious Elise for Gold/Platinum and diamond ranking in season 3
- Victorious Morgana for Gold and higher ranking in [season 4](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/competitive/end-season-rewards-and-new-master-tier)
- Victorious Sivir for Gold or higher ranking in season 5

Comment: You forgot the Jarvan skin for gaining gold and platinum on the ranked matches reptutation

Comment: You also forgot the Rammus skin from playing/having an account during the Beta.  "King Rammus".

Comment: Links for free skins:
Tristana:  http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=80451
Alistar: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/subscribe-riot-games-youtube-get-unchained-alistar

Answer (score 2):

Each week on tuesday Europe servers there are 10 free to play champions. Those can be looked up [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Free_champion_rotation#Current_champions). If you want to get the champs for free without paying for them you can use your influence points to buy them. But I suggest you try and play the champion first before you buy. Else you will be stuck with some champions you don't like playing, and will probably never play.

At times aswell if you want to throw some real cash to champions, Riot offers cheaper rp champions, only three or so.

As Raven Dreamer said there are only 2 champions that you get for free : Tristana and Alistar.

But my friend got myrmidon Pantheon for free on a smurf account he didn't play anymore, they gave him a key (to get him playing again), saying he will get the free skin and he just used his code on his main account. (Don't know if they still do this)

Not to mention if you play long enough till the end of season 2, and you win either gold or platinum you will get a free skin and if you just play 10 matches (Summoner Level 30 needed), you will probably get one too... atleast I hope they do that again

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for contributing. I wanted to point out that your answer had a lot of information in it that the question asker wasn't necessarily looking for. It seems like you re-iterated Raven's answer and then provided some additional commentary rather than providing any additional information on champions that the user could now get for free. Posts like this would be better as a comment on that previous answer you referenced. :)

Comment: Btw the summoner 30 level needed wasn't really needed... right after season 1 was out, ranked was for lvls 21 and above, if you played 10 ranked before at that time before you were level 30 and you didn't level up further you would have still gotten the skin ;). Thats why i was in elo hell before i was even lvl 30 :p

Comment: @Shaun Ah and btw, Raven Dreamer's awnser when i replied wasn't that "extended" he updated after my reply, wich is no problem by me i just won't delete my post for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

there is a lot of champions that riot Give to you when you gain the skin.

Sample:
Tristana, when you sign up in facebook page of Riot.
Alistar, when you sign up in youtube riot channel.
Kayle, if BEFORE the end of the first season you fight in 10+ games (any type, ranked or not, 5v5 or 3v3) with a premade (everyone in your team is invited then you start a fight with others friends, without random)

and Riot gives a LOT. take a look in riot site http://na.leagueoflegends.com/

you will notice that those skins are NOT available in the shop. Like Medieval Twitch (only available if you invite 350 people to lol, and they reach lv 10+) and gray warwick (inviting 50)

When you gain the skin, you gain the champion for free.

Every week riot change the free-week-champions rotation. This week for instance:
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/new-free-champion-rotation-preseason-week-3

you can check at the riot main page this kind of stuff too.

Here is how they pick the champions to free week: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=46045

i hope i helped you.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for contributing. I wanted to point out that your answer had a lot of information in it that the question asker wasn't necessarily looking for, such as info about temporary champion sales and the free-to-play champions. Information like this can make discovering the pertinent answer in your question somewhat difficult. If you limit your answer to items that focus on what the asker wanted to know, you'll end up with a clearer answer that is helpful to lots of people. :)